# Continous integration of Windows 8.1 project using Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, windows-store-apps, continuous-integration

I am trying to add a Windows 8.1 store app project to Jenkins for continous integration. The build server is not a Windows 8.1 machine. I am unable to build the project after checkout. 
Jenkins is giving error saying the MSBuild cannot find some files and unable to build. Is there any sdk that need to be installed on the build server.
Since the server is not a windows 8 ; installtion of VS 2013 is not possibel.

Can we setup a slave for compiling Win 8 projects?

Any help?

Comment: Why can't you install VS2013?  Our old build servers had Server 2008 and had VS2013 installed.  According to the compatibility page, VS2013 is even supported on Server 2003: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2013-compatibility-vs.aspx  Note: I am not recommending installing VS on the build server, but it certainly is possible.

Comment: @Lunyx I think you can't create Win8 apps on Win7 and before as the required runtimes/APIs are only available on Win8. **edit** By Win8 apps I mean Windows 8 metro/modern/store apps.

Comment: Is it possible to remote compile lie we do for iOS porjects?